# How to remove In-App Learning icon from global header?

Tags: lightning

With the Spring'21 release, Salesforce have added an In-App Learning icon to the global header.

[image]

Is there a way to remove this from the header?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot remove In-App Learning icon.  All users will have access to view the new icon in the global header and the panel.  Check more details [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_general_inapplearning.htm&release=230&type=5).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to remove the icon, but there is an active idea to allow it to be hidden.

Please vote for this idea, "Option to hide In-App Learning": https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0874V0000015KoMQAU

And if you are a Salesforce Partner, take a look of this: https://partners.salesforce.com/0D54V00005GZZMx